# IDEA new gradle spring boot project using GIT. What is the right creation sequence?

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I wanna start a new gradle spring boot project in IDEA and keep it at Git ( Bitbucket)

What is the most painless sequence to create it and store?

there are options:

1) create a repo at Bitbucket

2) clone it from IDEA

3) Generate a gradle project at spring boot starter page

4) import the gradle project from step 3 to IDEA.

(at this case IDEA says at the step 4 the folder is not empty and cancel)

So my question: what are the right steps?

Comment: 3, 4, initialize repo, add remote, commit/push.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [Spring Initializr](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#d729207e2) built into Intellij instead of the Initializr Website?

It uses the same [API backend](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/) to generate projects.

This is how I do it:

1. [Create project with Spring Initializer inside Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#d729207e2)
2. [Turn project into a Git repo](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#put-existing-project-under-Git)
3. Create remote repository in GitLab/Bitbucket/Github, etc.
4. [Add project to remote repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#add-remote)

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure of "It's the same" ? What if Spring boot starter Website makes some changes?

Comment: ok, i gonna go your way, then compare by some tools IDEA and Website files and merge changes if any

Comment: The Spring Initializr in Intellij uses the API of the Spring Initializr Website. It uses the same stuff: https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/

Comment: Do you mean IDEA checks everytime from the site are there any changes? if not, some day it will start to generate a bit different initial project...

Comment: Intellij doesn't generate the project, the API does. You are just invoking an API endpoint with parameters/choices and it's giving you the project. So every time you create one with the Initializer it is always the latest (you can even pick the version).

Comment: So in short: Yes, it checks every time :)